# Simple php post hook on Bitbucket doesn't work

Tags: php, bitbucket, webhooks

I'm having a problem with a post hook on bitbucket. It's a simple php script just a proof of concept:

```
<?php `cd /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules && git pull`;?>
```

In the log file I can see that Bitbucket is hitting my hook:

```
131.103.20.165 - - [27/May/2015:09:15:59 -0700] "POST /githubupdate.php HTTP/1.1" 200 70 "-" "Bitbucket.org"
```

But nothing is going on. If I try to run script manually as user apache it works fine:

```
sudo -u apache php /var/lib/foreman/public/githubupdate.php 
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From bitbucket.org:ucd-itservices/puppet-modules
   c083115..2ce4b73  production -> origin/production
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check user**

Please check if the webserver user is really `apache`.

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

If it is not, check that the user have enough permissions.

**SSH keys**

Are the SSH keys for Bitbucket (deployment keys) available or are you using only key forwarding via SSH?

**Check output**

Please check the output of the command:

```
<?php
echo nl2br(shell_exec('cd /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules && git pull');
?>
```

**Error logs**

Please check any Apache/PHP error logs for any error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The output for whoami:

`sudo -u apache php /var/lib/foreman/public/who.php 
apache`

I'm using deployment keys. I have a public key on Bitbucket in the repo settings under deployment key and private on my server under /var/www/.ssh for apache user.

The output for the nl2br command:

`sudo -u apache php /var/lib/foreman/public/n12br.php 
Already up-to-date.<br />`

I don't see any errors in my log files regarding php or apache.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but just try to open this test scripts via browser (because Bitbucket also does external requests).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand how I can see my results through browser. It's a remote server I open these scripts in browser from my desktop http(s)://servername/who.php. I can see the text from the scripts (<?php echo exec('whoami');?>) and the same time I can see the output in the log file for http `[28/May/2015:08:19:09 -0700] "GET /who.php HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36"`  So, I'm getting GET instead of POST. How I can hit these scripts to see the results?

Comment: You have to use a HTML form (or cURL) to make POST requests.

Comment: curl http://<servername>/who.php
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>

In the log file

 `[28/May/2015:08:37:59 -0700] "GET /who.php HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"`

But I'm prettu sure my web user is apache:

`ps auxf |grep httpd
root      1678  0.0  0.0 157308  3464 ?        Ss   May26   0:09 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1716  0.0  0.1 157492  4356 ?        S    May26   1:12  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd`

Comment: What does `echo echo('whoami');` say?

Comment: When I'm doing curl it's just showing me the text of the script 
`<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>`

Comment: @tyon: Then PHP is not working/being parsed on your webserver.

Comment: Why is it working when I execute the script from the command line? How I can fix it?

Comment: @tyon: You have to configure your Apache webserver to parse PHP (correctly).

Comment: Thanks Richard. You are right, everything is working now. Thanks a lot!